# Office AddIns sub menu inconsistent

Tags: ms-office, office365

Can anyone please explain why the Office Add-In sub menu appears inconsistent?

The image below shows the dialog displayed after selecting 'Insert', 'My Add-Ins', 'See All'.[image]

[image]

The 3 dialogs are from 3 machines that have the same version of Office installed, logged into the same live account and each machine has the same Trusted Location entry https://[???????].sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog/.

Yet i get 3 different sub menus. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you refer to the tabs/section inside the dialog? It appears you have 3 different catalogs configured and potentially different identities on each machine.  To give you context:

**My Add-ins** Tab: Shows all the add-ins for your current liveId/individual account.

**My Organization**: Only appears when you sideload an add-in via a file share. As you point out, via the trusted catalogs section on File>Options>Trust Center>Trusted Catalogs. We should probably rename that tab to "Developer" as reality is that is mostly intended for developers to sideload add-ins for testing purposes.

**Office 365**: This is the new [Centralized Deployment](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Deploy-Office-Add-ins-in-the-Office-365-Admin-Center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f) feature that is currently in preview. It only appears when you are signed-in with an organizational account AND the tenant you are connected to supports the feature

**Store**. Self-explanatory.

So, double check your configuration and make sure to restart the application as configuration changes might not take effect until you do.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply Humberto,

I now have my Add-ins appearing for Desktop Excel.

If I deploy my Add-ins via the Centralized Deployment method, and they appear under 'Office 365' in Desktop Excel, how do i access them in Excel Online? The sub menu only contains 'My AddIns', 'My Organisation' and 'Store'